# SQLAlchemy: Filter on 'in_' has no effect

Tags: sqlalchemy

The `in_` in the `filter` statement in this query seems to have no effect and I'm not sure why not. Is it in the right location?

```
session.query(A).options(subqueryload(A.b).subqueryload(B.c))\
.options(subqueryload(X.y).subqueryload(Y.z))\
.filter(C.key.in_([1,2,3]))\
.all()
```

I'm doing the `subqueryload`'s because I want to load all the data at once.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, you are not querying in C, right? Nor defining a join or anything like that. Anyway, I would suggest you provide a more concrete and less abstract example. It would be easier to help you if there is something one can reproduce and debug. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was hard to come by in the official docs, but @Imzcig was right, I was lacking the join of `C` in the example. It should have been:

```
session.query(A) \
.options( \
    subqueryload(A.b) \
    .subqueryload(B.c)) \
.join(B.c) \
.options( \
    subqueryload(X.y) \
    .subqueryload(Y.z)) \
.filter(C.key.in_([1,2,3])) \
.all()
```

I'm showing a not so trivial example since it's important to see where the `join` should go.